# Laravel 8 Fortify update image during updating profile

Tags: laravel, fortify

I can update my email and password but i can't udpate my profile photo.
Here is my code which i wrote.I don't know where I did it wrong, could you help me?I guess i missed something about of ProfileInformationController.php in Fortify

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user-profile-information.update') }}"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Photo') }}</label>

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="exampleInputName1">Profile Image Upload</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="profile_photo_path" class="form-control-file" id="profile_photo_path">
                                    </div>

                                </div> <!-- End Row  -->
                            </div>

                            

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') ?? auth()->user()->name }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') ?? auth()->user()->email }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="mb-0 form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Update Profile') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you're using the headless version of Laravel Fortify it doesn't come with the ability to upload profile images. The migration doesn't include an attribute for a profile photo and the code in the controller has nothing in it related to uploading a profile photo. Also, the documentation has no mention of being able to upload a profile photo.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify
Unless I'm missing something, this will have to be implemented on your end.

```
class ProfileInformationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the user's profile information.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\UpdatesUserProfileInformation  $updater
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request,
                           UpdatesUserProfileInformation $updater)
    {
        $updater->update($request->user(), $request->all());

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse('', 200)
                    : back()->with('status', 'profile-information-updated');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago but I have the solution. You need to enable the feature in the `config/jetstream.php` file.

```
Features::profilePhotos(),
```

That line and a few others are commented out. Just uncomment to use. I hope that helps some others who may be looking for the answer.